# Integer Objects not getting compared in compare function of Comparator

Tags: java

```
class MyComparator<Integer> implements Comparator<Integer>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if(o1>o2) // line no 3
         return 1;
         else if(o1==o2)
             return 0;
         else
             return -1;
    }
}
```

At line 3, neither unboxing is happening nor I am able to call intValue(). Please help in understanding this.

At Line 3, compile error is coming.

Comment: Why do you think those are `java.lang.Integer` objects?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: why not using `Integer#compareTo` if you have Integer objects ?

Comment: I can use that, but I am curious to know why this is not working.

Comment: What do you think `MyComparator<Integer>` does?

Comment: No wonder, line 3 is empty. :)

Comment: MyComparator<Interger>  extends Comparator<Integer> and implements one abstract method compare, but I am not able to understand why Integer is losing its semantics. Why I am not able to call intValue() on o1 or o2?

Answer (score 6):

You should remove `<Integer>` in `MyComparator<Integer>`. What happens here is that you declare a `Integer` as a *type-variable*. It is not `java.lang.Integer`, it is just some type-variable which the compiler knows nothing about.

Comment: Ok agree to your point, but when we remove Integer in MyComparator<Integer>, then how compiler is able to resolve that it is not a type variable? I am new to Generics, so don't mind if missed anything basic

Comment: @RishabShinghal: declare your class as `class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>`

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I understood lexicore's point and tried it also , it works totally fine. I am trying to understand why it works if we remove Integer.

Answer (score -1):

A secondary issue in this code, once you resolve the problem mentioned by lexicore.

```
if(o1==o2)
```

This is comparing by reference, because both operands are of reference type.

`==` is only the numeric equality operator if at least one of the operands is of numeric type (i.e. a primitive other than `boolean`).

Explicitly unbox:

```
if(o1.intValue()==o2.intValue())
```

Or check `o1  < o2`, which has no reference-valued counterpart, and thus will unbox wrapped numeric operands.

Comment: No, has nothing to do with `==`.

Comment: Ok. But then this is going to be OP's next issue, when the extraneous type variable is removed.

Comment: Yes, you are right about this.

Answer (score -1):

As lexicore mentioned, you don't type-annotate the method

```
class MyComparator <Integer> implements Comparator<Integer>
```

if you don't want to redefine Integer in that scope. Instead, use:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
      @Override
      public int compare (Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o2 - o1;
      }
}
```

to reference the well known Integer.

```
import java.util.*;

class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
      @Override
      public int compare (Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o2 - o1;
      }
}

public class CmpInt
{
    /** */
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int a[] = {1, 3, 7, 9, 4, 2, 5};
        List <Integer> li = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (int i: a)
            li.add (i);
        Comparator <Integer> ci = new MyComparator ();
        Collections.sort (li, ci);
        for (Integer ii: li)
            System.out.printf ("%d ", ii);
      System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use subtraction to compare integers, because the subtraction might overflow.

Comment: Use `o1.compareTo(o2)` or `Integer.compare(x,y)` in case of primitive `int` to avoid integer overflow.

Comment: @Pshemo or just don't try to reinvent the wheel with `MyComparator`, and use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Comment: The code demonstrates how to declare a comparator and that it compiles successful and operates, not how to implement the comparison. There is already a sufficient Comparator for Integer, AFAIK.